# center text in 1 div of 4, that are in a div

Tags: html, css

I have 4 div's that are in a div and i am trying to center the text in one of them. i am having trouble from what i can tell because of me using overflow:hidden ext. Is there a easy way to do this? This is my set up.

http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/amc4m/light/

```
<div id="phil">
<div id="phily" style="text-align:center">thankyou</div>
<div id="philly">mysite</div>
<div id="philly">mysite</div>
<div id="philly">mysite</div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: They look centered to me? whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just being legitimate i am changing the ids to classes (for uniqueness) and use `line-height` same as the div's `height` to center them vertically on to the div.

```
.phil {
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF5ee;
}
.phily {
    float:left;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px; /*<--- Here*/
    font-size: 2.2em;
    border: 5px solid #FFF5ee;
    text-align: center;
    height: 70px;
    width: 29%;
    background-color: red;
    color:black
}
.philly {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    border: 5px solid #FFF5ee;
    height: 46px;
    width: 21%;
    line-height:46px;  /*<--- Here*/
    background-color: red;
    color:#FFF5ee;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7Aky/)**

Comment: Thank you everyone. @PSL excatly what i was trying to do!. thanks a lot! I could find very little info on how to do that. i tried something like that like 3-4 times but for some reason i thought if the div was 90px i would use line-height:90px; and then i don't remember what but i was putting something else with it and setting that to like 45px. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try by transform your **id** into **classes** as id must be unique into your page:

```
<div class="phil">
 <div class="phily" style="text-align:center">thankyou</div>
 <div class="philly">mysite</div>
 <div class="philly">mysite</div>
 <div class="philly">mysite</div>
</div>
```

In your case, only the first id will apply your CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't to answer your question but you should be using `classes` not `ID's` for these elements...

`Classes` are for multiples of the same, `ID`'s have to be unique elements

```
<div id="phil">
 <div class="phily" style="text-align:center">thankyou</div>
 <div class="philly">mysite</div>
 <div class="philly">mysite</div>
 <div class="philly">mysite</div>
</div>
```